# Put or not put space between the requires?

Tags: javascript

I don't know what the javascript convention is about this, what is the correct understanding?

```js
const session =         require('express-session')
const express =         require("express");
const config =          require("config");
const path =            require('path')
const cors =            require('cors')
```

or

```js
const session = require('express-session')
const express = require("express");
const config = require("config");
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
```

which is most used in javascript? In python there is pep8 to regulate this, in javascript there is something similar?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JS equivalent of PEP 8, but I daresay the second is far more common. This is, however, an unsuitable question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the "require" aligned like your first example. The second example is pretty much ubiquitous. As far as "convention" goes, I think most Javascript developers use a formatter like prettier and never think about code style again, and that's what I would recommend.

Comment: I've seen it several times like the first example, but I never understood why.